# A query which pulls below result with key-value pairs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

Context:
I am working in one cluster datastax dse 5.1.8 with spark  version 2.0.2.17 and Scala version 2.11.11.

Problem:
I am a table with this structure definition

```
CREATE TABLE test (
location text,
cell text,
testdate timestamp,
model text,
testnumber bigint,
reading bigint,
scan bigint,
testtype text,
readingtype text,
payloadtype text,
datatype text,
measurementid timeuuid,
aircraftengineposition text,
aircrafttailnumber text,
aircrafttypename text,
analysisnumber bigint,
archiveddate timestamp,
archivemethod text,
createddate timestamp,
edwid bigint,
engineserialnumber text,
etdscampus text,
etdsrecordid bigint,
etdssetid bigint,
fleet text,
flightnumber text,
jnumber bigint,
method text,
modifieddate timestamp,
parameters map<text, frozen<tuple<text, text, bigint, double, text>>>,
payloadchecksum blob,
payloadlocation text,
payloaduri text,
payloaduserreference text,
powerset text,
rating text,
status text,
vehicle text,
PRIMARY KEY ((location, cell, testdate, model, testnumber, reading, scan, testtype, readingtype, payloadtype, datatype), measurementid)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (measurementid DESC)
```

My primary keys is:
    location, cell, testdate, model, testnumber, reading, 
    scan,testtype,readingtype, payloadtype, datatype

When i query this table by using the column parameters from cassandra i get tuple below for one row for example:

```
{'PF121A': ('R', None, None, 1131.65942, None), 'PT25AA': ('R', None, None, 29.40011, None), 'PT25AB': ('R', None, None, 29.83459, None), 'PT25AC': ('R', None, None, 29.93993, None), 'PT25AD': ('R', None, None, 14.02732, None), 'PT25AE': ('R', None, None, 31.12416, None), 'PT25AF': ('R', None, None, 31.06807, None), 'PT25SA': ('R', None, None, 14.02681, None), 'PT25SB': ('R', None, None, 29.39588, None), 'PT25SC': ('R', None, None, 29.6147, None), 'PT25SD': ('R', None, None, 29.97557, None), 'PT25SE': ('R', None, None, 30.94819, None), 'PT25SF': ('R', None, None, 30.66682, None), 'PT31FA': ('R', None, None, 814.65393, None), 'PT31FB': ('R', None, None, 818.90576, None), 'PT31FC': ('R', None, None, 819.23676, None), 'PT31FD': ('R', None, None, 814.65485, None), 'PT31FE': ('R', None, None, 814.4751, None), 'PT31FF': ('R', None, None, 813.31396, None), 'PT31RA': ('R', None, None, 812.73108, None), 'PT31RB': ('R', None, None, 814.26917, None), 'PT31RC': ('R', None, None, 814.9386, None), 'PT31RD': ('R', None, None, 814.97534, None), 'PT31RE': ('R', None, None, 814.57043, None), 'PT31RF': ('R', None, None, 813.4953, None), 'PT49JA': ('R', None, None, 137.66408, None), 'PT49JB': ('R', None, None, 136.09262, None), 'PT49JC': ('R', None, None, 134.53801, None), 'PT49JD': ('R', None, None, 135.47989, None), 'PT49JE': ('R', None, None, 134.17297, None), 'PT49WA': ('R', None, None, 138.44234, None), 'PT49WB': ('R', None, None, 136.7596, None), 'PT49WC': ('R', None, None, 135.41495, None), 'PT49WD': ('R', None, None, 135.69455, None), 'PT49WE': ('R', None, None, 133.96593, None), 'PT50EA': ('R', None, None, 20.66105, None), 'PT50EB': ('R', None, None, 20.15389, None), 'PT50EC': ('R', None, None, 20.01845, None), 'PT50ED': ('R', None, None, 19.94046, None), 'PT50EE': ('R', None, None, 14.02631, None), 'PT50EF': ('R', None, None, 20.40714, None), 'PT50SA': ('R', None, None, 20.47363, None), 'PT50SB': ('R', None, None, 19.98885, None), 'PT50SC': ('R', None, None, 19.87228, None), 'PT50SD': ('R', None, None, 19.74927, None), 'PT50SE': ('R', None, None, 19.84222, None), 'PT50SF': ('R', None, None, 14.0299, None), 'PUBDAT': ('R', None, None, 14717, None), 'PUBTIM': ('R', None, None, 6.1759e+07, None), 'TACALL': ('R', None, None, 217.15161, None), 'TACALR': ('R', None, None, 215.13361, None), 'TACAUL': ('R', None, None, 192.04047, None), 'TACAUR': ('R', None, None, 207.94643, None), 'TACFLL': ('R', None, None, 166.98624, None), 'TACFLR': ('R', None, None, 153.83304, None), 'TACFUL': ('R', None, None, 180.14462, None), 'TACFUR': ('R', None, None, 168.80762, None), 'TACMUL': ('R', None, None, 183.63214, None), 'TACMUR': ('R', None, None, 111.59378, None), 'TM25AA': ('R', None, None, 209.83342, None), 'TM25AB': ('R', None, None, 209.16489, None), 'TM25AC': ('R', None, None, 209.9166, None), 'TM25AD': ('R', None, None, 216.28339, None), 'TM25AE': ('R', None, None, 221.4989, None), 'TM25AF': ('R', None, None, 227.64745, None), 'TM25SA': ('R', None, None, 209.70547, None), 'TM25SB': ('R', None, None, 208.61472, None), 'TM25SC': ('R', None, None, 208.71387, None), 'TM25SD': ('R', None, None, 212.55757, None), 'TM25SE': ('R', None, None, 222.05238, None), 'TM25SF': ('R', None, None, 227.34381, None), 'TM31FA': ('R', None, None, 1303.27625, None), 'TM31FB': ('R', None, None, 1302.17749, None), 'TM31FC': ('R', None, None, 1301.16431, None), 'TM31FD': ('R', None, None, 1300.43945, None), 'TM31FE': ('R', None, None, 1306.04688, None), 'TM31FF': ('R', None, None, 1308.64978, None), 'TM31RA': ('R', None, None, 1308.25098, None), 'TM31RB': ('R', None, None, 1307.29443, None), 'TM31RC': ('R', None, None, 1307.47229, None), 'TM31RD': ('R', None, None, 1308.46118, None), 'TM31RE': ('R', None, None, 1311.94226, None), 'TM31RF': ('R', None, None, 1317.01111, None), 'TM50EA': ('R', None, None, 1066.51196, None), 'TM50EB': ('R', None, None, 1037.17004, None), 'TM50EC': ('R', None, None, 1035.68445, None), 'TM50ED': ('R', None, None, 1030.4646, None), 'TM50EE': ('R', None, None, 1022.53888, None), 'TM50EF': ('R', None, None, 1016.54425, None), 'TM50SA': ('R', None, None, 1064.77722, None), 'TM50SB': ('R', None, None, 1044.97632, None), 'TM50SC': ('R', None, None, 1044.73755, None), 'TM50SD': ('R', None, None, 1046.18323, None), 'TM50SE': ('R', None, None, 1047.10889, None), 'TM50SF': ('R', None, None, 1042.55457, None), 'XNHCT1': ('R', None, None, 10639.88574, None), 'XNLCT1': ('R', None, None, 2448.99121, None)}
```

My problem is to use scala query which allow me to pull result above with key value pair, example to have from the result above these example:

```
KEY: VALUE PAIR

PF121A: 1131.65942
PT25AA: 29.40011 
PT25AB: 29.83459 
PT25AC: 29.93993 
PT25AD: 14.02732
PT25AE: 31.12416 
PT25AF: 31.06807
```

Below the first query i used from spark but i don't know how to continue:

```
scala> val parameters = sc.cassandraTable(String).select("parameters")
parameters: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD[String] = CassandraTableScanRDD[1] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:19
```

result for 5 lines:

```
scala> parameters.take(10)
res1: Array[String] = Array({PT25AF: (R, null, null, 14.898366928100586, null),PT31RD: (R, null, null, 73.38668060302734, null),PT49WD: (R, null, null, 20.127065658569336, null),TM50SC: (R, null, null, 803.0751342773438, null),PT50SE: (R, null, null, 14.305357933044434, null),TACAUL: (R, null, null, 211.5594940185547, null),PT31RE: (R, null, null, 73.51492309570312, null),PT31FE: (R, null, null, 73.38947296142578, null),TM50SF: (R, null, null, 810.0723876953125, null),PT50ED: (R, null, null, 14.262494087219238, null),PT49JC: (R, null, null, 20.577911376953125, null),TACMUR: (R, null, null, 113.4200668334961, null),TM50EF: (R, null, null, 802.0999145507812, null),PT50EE: (R, null, null, 14.02810001373291, null),PT25SC: (R, null, null, 14.932862281799316, null),PT25AA: (R, null, null, 14..
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/4_mapper.md

Comment: Thanks. i read this document but i did not find solution about my problem.